# Scrollbar appears next to sliding-menu

Tags: html, css, cordova, phonegap-build, onsen-ui

I have an ons-list(basically a list) in my view that I want to have a scrollbar, so I added some css to my index.html, namely the following one:

```
    <style>
    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
        display: block !important;
        width: 5px;
        height: 0px;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        border-radius: 2px;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
    }
</style>
```

This helps with the scollbar problem for the ons-list, but it also shows an "external" scrollbar to the whole page that is always there.

Is there any way to remove that?

Here's a screenshot to show you what i'm talking about:

[image]

You can see, that the scrollbar is tied to the main page, because in the following screenshot, I'm sliding the ons-sliding-menu to the left, and the scrollbar is tied to the main page.
[image]

Index.html looks like this :

```
<ons-sliding-menu main-page="navigator.html" menu-page="menu.html" side="right" max-slide-distance="250px" var="menu">
</ons-sliding-menu>

<ons-template id="menu.html">
    <ons-page ng-controller="menuController" ng-init="initMenu()">
      <ons-list>
        <ons-list-item modifier="tappable" onclick="menu.setMainPage('navigator.html', {closeMenu: true})">
          <ons-icon icon="ion-home" style="padding-bottom:2px;"></ons-icon>  Home
        </ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item modifier="tappable" onclick="menu.setMainPage('Page1.html', {closeMenu: true})">
          <ons-icon icon="ion-clipboard" style="padding-bottom:2px;"></ons-icon>  Page1
        </ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item modifier="tappable" onclick="menu.setMainPage('Page2.html', {closeMenu: true})">
          <ons-icon icon="ion-loop" style="padding-bottom:2px;"></ons-icon>  Page2
        </ons-list-item>
      </ons-list>
  </ons-page>
</ons-template>

<ons-template id="navigator.html">
    <ons-navigator title="Navigator" var="myNavigator" page="main.html">        
    </ons-navigator>
</ons-template>

<ons-template id="main.html">
        <ons-page id="main" >
            <ons-tabbar>
                <ons-tab active="true" page="page_1.html">
                    <div class="tab">
                        <ons-icon icon="ion-calendar" class="tab-icon"></ons-icon>
                        <div class="tab-label">Page_1</div>
                    </div>
                </ons-tab>
                <ons-tab page="settings.html">
                    <div class="tab">
                        <ons-icon icon="ion-gear-a" class="tab-icon"></ons-icon>
                        <div class="tab-label">Settings</div>
                    </div>
                </ons-tab>
            </ons-tabbar>
        </ons-page>
</ons-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the body content is taking more space and resulting in the outer scroll bar.

You can try this to avoid the outer scroll bar -

```
body {
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the body fix didn't help. I added a new screenshot which shows, that when I slide the page to the left, to bring the sliding-menu in, the scrollbar is not on the body anymore, but the main page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're using Onsen 1, since these issues shouldn't be present in Onsen 2. Apart from upgrading you can do the thing which @Nitesh suggested - just write `overflow: hidden` on the elements which you don't want to have a scrollbar.

The trick is that these scrollbars probably don't come from the body, but more likely from `ons-page`. Those pages insert a `.page__content` and put your content there. So you could try something like

```
.page__content {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Or if you're sure that the one which you don't want comes from the main page you could do something like:

```
#main > .page__content {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

If that doesn't help you should be able to debug the problem in a browser. `right click -> inspect element` and you can find the specific element which has the scrollbar.

An alternative would be not to change the styles of the scrollbars by default, but just to use the `ons-scrollbar` tag wherever you want a scrollbar.